# Android two different SharedPreference types with the same ID

Tags: android

Currently I want to store two different data types as SharedPreference in my android app. Is it possible to store them with the same key-value?

e.g:

```
int id = 123;
myBoolean = false;
myString = "hello";

SharedPreferences.Editor edit = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
edit.putString(String.valueOf(id), myString);
edit.putBoolean(String.valueOf(id), myBoolean);
```

because currently, when I try to get the string value I get a ClassCast exception here:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
String myString = settings.getString(String.valueOf(123), "def");
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Comment: You used a boolean last time so you have to use getBoolean - String.ValueOf (settings.getBoolean(String.valueOf(123), "def"));

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I expect the result of myString to be "hello", not the value of the boolean

Comment: Oh, I think you cannot do that

Comment: Seems not, I've already implemented a work around, but was still curious if it was doable

Comment: A key can have only a value, it does not store another if you change the data type,  it overwrites it.

Comment: Yes, thank you for clearing it up for me :O)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible, Shared Preferences is a key value pair (the key is unique). What your code does is replace the previous saved value. So, when you try to get the value you receive a boolean.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to be any better than this!